# CF Workers - Download the script

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I've lost the repository for my Cloudflare worker and I can't seem to find any information to get it neither from the dashboard, nor wrangler.

Is there a way to download the worker without its git repository? It was published via wrangler.

Comment: Is the state currently supposed to be published? It's odd that it wouldn't show up under the dashboard. Have you looked under the zone's environment variables or  under the global KV namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button for Online editing is now visible.
Maybe was some CloudFlare maintenance.